# Unable to login after adding server in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

After adding the another server which is in my network through IP address.It connect successfully.But as and when I logout from console it done not allow me to login from my credential.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've added the server but didn't rebalance it.
try to rebalance the cluster and do it again.

Comment: When I added the server it automatically re-balanced then and there.